# Compare binary integers ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitmask

I am working with a master bitmask in Ruby that contains a list of settings. I have converted the bitmask to binary and need to compare it to other binary values to see if certain setting exists.

For example, I start with the bitmask:

```
bitmask = 1540104
```

Then convert to binary using:

```
binary = bitmask.to_s(2) => 101111000000000001000
```

Since each 1 in that master binary represents a single setting, how can I iterate over that result to see each 1's placement in the context of the 21 digit binary? Like so:

```
100000000000000000000
001000000000000000000
000100000000000000000
000010000000000000000
000001000000000000000
000000000000000001000
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with it, just use hash instead IMO. Size improvements of <1kB are not worth code complications and the hassle IMO.

Comment: 21 bits enables you to have 2^21(2097152) different settings config. Do you really have that many settings in your app? Anyway, if you must do this, you can just AND these to digits. If a bitmask has a particular setting bit in it, it will return 1 otherwise it would be 0. E.G.: `"100000000000000000000".to_i(2) & bitmask #=> 1` while: `"010000000000000000000".to_i(2) & bitmask #=> 0`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you want to check whether a specific bit is set or do you want to have some debug output?

Comment: @ericalli I have a strong feel that you are asking a question about an intermediate step of solving your real problem. However, this step is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how can I iterate over that result to see each 1's placement in the context of the 21 digit binary?

If you just want to *see* the bits, i.e. for debugging purposes, you could solve it via [`Integer#bit_length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-bit_length), [`Integer#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) and some bit shifting:

```
bitmask = 1540104

bitmask.bit_length.downto(0) do |n|
  printf("%.*b\n", bitmask.bit_length, 1 << n) unless bitmask[n].zero?
end
```

Output:

```
100000000000000000000
001000000000000000000
000100000000000000000
000010000000000000000
000001000000000000000
000000000000000001000
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to show the placements of the `1`'s is to simply display their bit positions.

```
bitmask = 1540104

puts bitmask.bit_length.times.map { |i| [i, bitmask[i]] }.
             select { |_, b| b == 1 }.
             map { |i,_| "%2d" % i }
 3
15
16
17
18
20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bitmask = 1540104    
bitmask.to_s(2).each_char.with_index(0) {|b, index| puts (1 << index).to_s(2).rjust(bitmask.bit_length, "0").reverse if b == "1"}
```

Output:

```
100000000000000000000
001000000000000000000
000100000000000000000
000010000000000000000
000001000000000000000
000000000000000001000
```